# Cannot trait an inherited class as base with SFINAE

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, traits, sfinae

I create a `container_traits` class to check if a container is `std::array` or not.
But it fails to catch a container inherited from `std::array`.
Any solutions?

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename C>
struct container_traits { constexpr static bool is_array = false; };
template<typename T, size_t S>
struct container_traits<std::array<T,S>> { constexpr static bool is_array = true; };

template<typename T, size_t S>
struct A : public std::array<T,S> {};

int main()
{
    cout << container_traits<A<int, 5>>::is_array << endl;              // must return 1
    cout << container_traits<std::array<int, 10>>::is_array << endl;    // must return 1
    cout << container_traits<std::vector<int>>::is_array << endl;       // must return 0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried enable_if with __is_base_of type_traits?

Comment: @Alon: Don't you dare use double-underscore stuff! Those are implementation details, don't touch them. Use just `std::is_base_of` instead.

Comment: Inheritance or templates? Pick one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `std::is_base_of`:

```
template <typename C>
struct container_traits {
  constexpr static bool is_array = false;
};

template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C,
          typename T, std::size_t N>
struct container_traits<C<T,N>> {
  constexpr static bool is_array = std::is_base_of<std::array<T,N>, C<T,N>>::value;
};
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/HBssdK).

It's basically specialized for any template type that takes two parameters. And in that specialization, the value of `is_array` is determined by `std::is_base_of`.

Comment: +1 for is_base_of avoiding the public/non-public inheritance issue.

Answer (score 6):

**Author's note: Please, don't vote for this solution. Vote for sftrabbit's instead because it's better than mine.** I won't delete though because, although flawed, some found the idea interesting .

This gives the results that you want:

```
template<typename C>
struct container_traits {

private:

   template <typename T, size_t N>
   static char (&is_array_helper(const std::array<T, N>&))[1];

   static char (&is_array_helper(...))[2];

public:

    constexpr static bool is_array =
        sizeof(is_array_helper(std::declval<C>())) == sizeof(char[1]);

};
```

**Note**:

It's worth mentioning that for a class which derives from `std::array<T, N>` (e.g. `A`) the inheritance must be `public` otherwise the code doesn't compile. To fix this, may be, you can use `std::is_base_of` or apply some SFINAE technique. However, SFINAE rules regarding accessibility have changed from C++03 to C++11 and when I tested a while ago, some major compilers didn't implement the new rules. May be they do now.

I suggest the question's author to wait to see if a better solution comes up (I wish this will happen).

Comment: @Alon is there much to explain?  It is pretty basic SFINAE based off of function overloads.

Comment: Well I've never seen it done like that before. Interesting solution.

Comment: @sftrabbit: I'm not sure but I believe the original idea (using overload and checking the sizes of returning types) is Andrei Alexandrescu's.